# Ghost file throwing "Linker command failed with exit code 1" in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to archive my project and a ghost file that has no name. I cannot open it and finder is throwing an error "Linker command failed with exit code 1".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right clicking and choosing "Review in Log" solved my problem.